# Mongodb index for nested objects

Tags: mongodb, indexing

i have documents in my colllection in that schema:

```
    {
    "schedule":  {
        "day_of_week": {
            "0": {"hour": {"3": [60], "6": [45, 60], "9": [60]}},
            "2": {"hour": {"2": [60], "3": [45, 60], "5": [60]}},
            "3": {"hour": {"1": [15, 45], "4": [30], "5": [60], "6": [30, 60], "7": [45]}},
            "6": {"hour": {"1": [30], "2": [15, 45, 60], "5": [30], "9": [15, 45]}}
        }
    }
   }
```

And i have query to find this documents:

```
db.my_coll.find({"schedule.day_of_week.0.hour.3":60})
```

What index i should create for optimize my query?

I already create these indexes:

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "db.my_coll"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "schedule.day_of_week.0.hour" : 1
            },
            "name" : "schedule.day_of_week.0.hour_1",
            "ns" : "db.my_coll"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "schedule.day_of_week.0" : 1
            },
            "name" : "schedule.day_of_week.0_1",
            "ns" : "db.my_coll"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "schedule.day_of_week" : 1
            },
            "name" : "schedule.day_of_week_1",
            "ns" : "db.my_coll"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "schedule" : 1
            },
            "name" : "schedule_1",
            "ns" : "db.my_coll"
    }
```

]

but it does not make any effect, query still doing COLLSCAN without using index.

Output of db.my_coll.explain(1).find({"schedule.day_of_week.0.hour.3":‌​60})

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 64,
    "nscanned" : 64,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 64,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 64,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "allPlans" : [
            {
                    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 2,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 64,
                    "nscanned" : 64,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0
            }
    ],
    "server" : "server:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
            "type" : "COLLSCAN",
            "works" : 66,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 2,
            "needTime" : 63,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "docsTested" : 64,
            "children" : [ ]
    }
```

}

In collection 64 documents

Comment: What is output of `db.my_coll.explain(1).find({"schedule.day_of_week.0.hour.3":60})`

Comment: i posted output

Comment: all documents are in memory. Indices are used to fetch data from disk efficiently. No index was used hence.

Comment: Yes, and my question is "What index i should create to optimize my query?" I want to use index but i dont know what kind of index i should create.

Comment: you dont need an index for 64 docs. Incase you are putting in more docs an index on `schedule.day_of_week.0.hour` would be the correct one

Comment: its just example ;-) in production collection will be about 100 thousand